# switch function executing several cases

Tags: android, android-intent, gridview, android-studio

Hi I have been facing a problem since a while and I can't seem to find a solution.
I have a gridview with three items, and every one opens an activity when selected. The problem comes when I select the `case 0` it first opens the `intent i` then the `intent ii` and ends up with opening the `intent iii`.

If I select `case 1`, I open first `intent ii` and then `intent iii`.
Finally if I select `case 2` I open `intent iii`. THis is the main code!

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mItems = new ArrayList<GridViewItem>();
        Resources resources = getResources();

        mItems.add(new GridViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.truck_package), getString(R.string.drop_package)));
        mItems.add(new GridViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.man_package), getString(R.string.pick_package)));
        mItems.add(new GridViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.register), getString(R.string.register)));
        mAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, mItems);
        // initialize the GridView
        final GridView gridView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0 :
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DropPackage.class);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DropPack", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(i);

                    case 1 :
                        Intent ii = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PickPackage.class);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PickPack", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(ii);
                    case 2 :
                        Intent iii = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Register.class);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Register", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(iii);
                }



            }
        });
    }
```

Any idea of what could be the problem? Thank you :)

Comment: `Any idea of what could be the problem?` Yes, you also know problem i think but solution is :: `break;`

Comment: your switch is not switching.

Comment: Oh @ρяσѕρєяK you are right!!! such a stupid question! Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post that as an answer so this doesn't show as unanswered?

Comment: @nasch: please provide answer for this question.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not put `break` at the end of case statements.
Try adding break at the end  of every `case` statement.

Try this way

```
switch (position){
    case 0 :
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DropPackage.class);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DropPack", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    case 1 :
        Intent ii = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PickPackage.class);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PickPack", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(ii);
        break;

    case 2 :
        Intent iii = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Register.class);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Register", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(iii);
        break;
}
```